# Import non-core npm Library into Angular 2 App

Tags: angular, typescript, module, webpack

Hi I am new to Angular 2 and I am having a hard time importing the Regression npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/regression
within my Angular 2 application to use the Linear Regression function. My build consists of Angular 2, Webpack, and TypeScript.
So far I have `npm install regression` and included the script tag within my index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/regression/src/regression.js"></script>
```

I have also Regression within my App.Module

```
import * as Regression from 'regression;
```

This is how I am trying to use the regression function but it is showing that the function cannot be found:

```
let actualXY = [];
for (var j = 0; j <= 11; j++) {
        let entry = [];
        entry[0] = j+1;
        entry[1] = m.actuals[j];
        actualXY[j] = entry;
}
var result = regression('linear', actualXY);
```

Is there any steps I'm missing to import the Regression package or is this simply not possible?

Comment: have you tried to just npm install regression?

Comment: With webpack, you do not need to add the script tag to the HTML file, it will get picked up automatically. Otherwise, see 5313M's answer. Does the error occur on the import or where you use it?

Comment: Did you found the solution, I am also facing the same issue, Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As your import illustrates : `import * as Regression from 'regression;` , thus you should use `Regression` not `regression`, so it should be `Regression('linear', actualXY);` instead. Also, there is a missed `quote` after the imported `regression`. **PS**: I do not know what is *regression* but I've answered from a logical point of view.