# How to use "regression-js" in angular 2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, linear-regression

I am importing the Regression npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/regression within my Angular 2 application to use the Linear Regression function. I have install package using `"npm install regression"` . Now I have tried few things to use that package :

**First thing which i have tried:**

```
import regression from 'regression';
const result= regression.linear([0, 1], [32, 67], [12, 79]); // this line is giving error, -- can not use linear on undefined.
```

**Second thing which I have tried:**

```
import {Regression} from "regression";
regresiionvar: Regression;
const result=  this.regresiionvar.linear([0, 1], [32, 67], [12, 79]); // but still undefined error.
```

**third thing which I have tried:**

```
import {Regression} from "regression";
regresiionvar: Regression = new Regression().init({});
const result=  this.regresiionvar.linear([0, 1], [32, 67], [12, 79]);//  but still the same undefined error.
```

I do not know, which thing I am missing, this is quite popular package(look at the number of downloads daily.)

Can any one please share the working example of [regression-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regression) with angular 2.

I found one similar question for this, [Import non-core npm Library into Angular 2 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556317/import-non-core-npm-library-into-angular-2-app#comment81532045_41556317) , but it also do not have any correct solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On version 1.4.0 of regression-js you can import it like this

```
import * as regression from 'regression';
```

And then use it like this

```
const reg = regression('linear', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
const regression = require('regression');
```

Comment: @Fiddles I don't know the details. It works on my machine